# Best way to sort table based on headers using Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I have my table that gets generated based on what's in the database and would like to add the ability to sort the table based on particular columns. I tried looking online but since the table isn't static, I'm not sure how to properly add in the ability to sort.

```
<table class="table" style="border: 3px solid black;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="border-left: 1px solid #eee;" class="align-middle">Select</th>
            <th class="align-middle">Col1</th>
            <th class="align-middle">Col2</th>
            <th class="align-middle">Col3</th>
            <th class="align-middle">Col4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for row in data %}
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="inputSelect" value="{{ row[0], row[3] }}"></td>
            <td>{{ row[0] }}</td>
            <td>{{ row[1] }}</td>
            <td>{{ row[2] }}</td>
            <td>{{ row[3] }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Try the first answer of: [How to make bootstrap-table-filter-control work with Flask, Jinja and Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61987454/how-to-make-bootstrap-table-filter-control-work-with-flask-jinja-and-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, this worked really well for me: https://datatables.net/manual/installation

Comment: I was about to post the same link :)

Comment: But is this really the best way to sort table columns using flask?

Answer (score 0):

One solution for creating sortable tables is within [flask-tables](https://flask-table.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). The linked article also has a minimal example in [solution.py](https://github.com/plumdog/flask_table/blob/master/examples/sortable.py).

The full example is found in `solution.py`, but the most important parts are:

```
class SortableTable(Table):
    id = Col('ID')
    name = Col('Name')
    description = Col('Description')
    link = LinkCol(
        'Link', 'flask_link', url_kwargs=dict(id='id'), allow_sort=False)
    allow_sort = True

    def sort_url(self, col_key, reverse=False):
        if reverse:
            direction = 'desc'
        else:
            direction = 'asc'
        return url_for('index', sort=col_key, direction=direction)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    sort = request.args.get('sort', 'id')
    reverse = (request.args.get('direction', 'asc') == 'desc')
    table = SortableTable(Item.get_sorted_by(sort, reverse),
                          sort_by=sort,
                          sort_reverse=reverse)
    return table.__html__()
```

In case you want to combine this with Pandas like me, this is a minimal example that can help you:

```
from flask_table import Table, Col
from flask import Flask, request, url_for
import pandas as pd

"""
A example for creating a Table that is sortable by its header
"""

app = Flask(__name__)


class SortableTable(Table):
    id = Col('ID')
    name = Col('Name')
    description = Col('Description')
    allow_sort = True

    def sort_url(self, col_key, reverse=False):
        if reverse:
            direction = 'desc'
        else:
            direction = 'asc'
        return url_for('index', sort=col_key, direction=direction)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    df = pd.DataFrame([
        (1, 'G', 'zzzzz'),
        (2, 'U', 'aaaaa'),
        (3, 'I', 'bbbbb')], columns=["id", "name", "description"])

    sort = request.args.get('sort', 'id')
    reverse = (request.args.get('direction', 'asc') == 'desc')

    df = df.sort_values(by=[sort], ascending=reverse)
    output_dict = df.to_dict(orient='records')

    table = SortableTable(output_dict,
                          sort_by=sort,
                          sort_reverse=reverse)
    return table.__html__()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```