# How to make bootstrap-table-filter-control work with Flask, Jinja and Dataframe

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2, bootstrap-table

I'm using python Flask render_template to return a html page for a route of my python app, and in the html I want to use the bootstrap-table-filter-control as described in the bootstrap [example here](https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/#extensions/filter-control.html). However the example given seem to be using a table from a local json file. Here's the code given in the example:

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.16.0/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.16.0/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.16.0/dist/extensions/filter-control/bootstrap-table-filter-control.min.js"></script>

<table
  id="table"
  data-url="json/data1.json"   ## this looks like the code to get the table's data
  data-filter-control="true"
  data-show-search-clear-button="true">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="id">ID</th>
      <th data-field="name" data-filter-control="input">Item Name</th>
      <th data-field="price" data-filter-control="select">Item Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#table').bootstrapTable()
  })
</script>
```

How do I replace the

> data-url="json/data1.json"

with my own table from my python dataframe passed from the main.py app? I tried the below for my html but it doesn't work:

> ```
>         {% for table in tables %}
>             <table id="table"
>                 data = {{ table|safe }}
>                 data-filter-control="true"
>                 data-show-search-clear-button="true"
>                 class="table-striped">
>
>                 <thead>
>                     <tr>
>                         <th data-field="columnA" data-filter-control="input">column A</th>
>                         <th data-field="columnB" data-filter-control="select">columnB</th>
>                         <th data-field="columnC" data-filter-control="select">columnC</th>
>                     </tr>
>                 </thead>
>                 <tbody>
>                    <!-- I have tried to put {{ table|safe }} here but doesn't work -->
>                 </tbody>
>             </table>
>         {% endfor %}
> ```

My python route looks like this:

```
@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return render_template('yield.html',  tables=[df3.to_html(classes='data', header="true")])
```

where df3 is the dataframe I want to display as a table in the yield.html with bootstrap filter controls.

Answer (score 7):

After some back to basics step-by-step testing, I found my own solution and it's working like a charm now. My yield.html looks like this, with the bootstrap-table filter controls, search, and sorting enabled:

```
<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
 <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.16.0/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.16.0/extensions/filter-control/bootstrap-table-filter-control.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
                <table id="table"
                    data-toggle="table"
                    data-filter-control="true"
                    data-show-search-clear-button="true"
                    data-sortable="true"
                    classes="table-sm"
                    data-pagination="true"
                    data-show-columns="true"
                    data-show-columns-toggle-all="true"
                    class="table-responsive">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <!--special characters and spaces not allowed in data-field name-->
                            <th data-field="columnA" data-filter-control="input" data-sortable="true">column A</th>
                            <th data-field="columnB" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">column B</th>
                            <th data-field="columnC" data-filter-control="input" data-sortable="true">column C</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {% for row in tableA %}
                        <tr>
                            <!--special characters and spaces not allowed in data-field name-->
                            <td>{{ row.columnA }}</td>
                            <td>{{ row.columnB }}</td>
                            <td>{{ row.columnC }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
    </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.16.0/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.16.0/dist/extensions/filter-control/bootstrap-table-filter-control.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Notably, instead of calling an entire table that was made by to_html (dataframe to complete html table with header and row tags included) in the main.py app, I have to specify the table header specifically (within thead tags) with each column's parameters stated clearly, and no spaces and special characters allowed in the data-field name of header, and then to pull in the data rows using the {% for row in tableA %} with the corresponding column names.

In my python app, my data was from a dataframe, which I would need to convert to a python data type, specifically python dictionary that is list like, using  `data = df.to_dict('records')` 
And when i render the template, I can pass this dictionary over to the template using     `return render_template('yield.html', tableA = data)`

My python app route looks like this:

```
@app.route('/')
def hello():
    data = df.to_dict('records')
    return render_template('yield.html', tableA = data)
```

Comment: You just changed my life with this example, lol. So many uses! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A simple example of use bootstrap-table and flask.

Structure:

```sh
├── app.py
└── templates
    └── table.html
```

Table.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
  <title>Bootstrap Table - Flask example </title>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.11.1/bootstrap-table.min.css">
  <script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.11.1/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
  <style type='text/css'>
    .row-index {
      width: 50px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
  </style>

  <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(window).load(function(){
      var data = {{data|tojson}};
      var columns = {{columns|tojson}};

      $(function() {
        $('#table').bootstrapTable({ 
          data: data,
          columns: columns,
        });

      });

    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container" style="padding: 10px; ">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <br/>
    <div id="toolbar"></div>
    <table
      id="table"
      data-toggle="true"
      data-toolbar="#toolbar"
      data-search="true"
      data-show-columns="true"
      data-pagination="true"
      data-height="500">
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

app.py:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
import json

"""
A example for creating a Table that is sortable by its header
"""

app = Flask(__name__)
data = [{
  "name": "bootstrap-table",
  "commits": "10",
  "attention": "122",
  "uneven": "An extended Bootstrap table"
},
 {
  "name": "multiple-select",
  "commits": "288",
  "attention": "20",
  "uneven": "A jQuery plugin"
}, {
  "name": "Testing",
  "commits": "340",
  "attention": "20",
  "uneven": "For test"
}]
# other column settings -> http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/#column-options
columns = [
  {
    "field": "name", # which is the field's name of data key 
    "title": "name", # display as the table header's name
    "sortable": True,
  },
  {
    "field": "commits",
    "title": "commits",
    "sortable": True,
  },
  {
    "field": "attention",
    "title": "attention",
    "sortable": True,
  },
  {
    "field": "uneven",
    "title": "uneven",
    "sortable": True,
  }
]

#jdata=json.dumps(data)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("table.html",
      data=data,
      columns=columns,
      title='Flask Bootstrap Table')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #print jdata
  app.run(debug=True)
```

Output:
[image]

Reference: [bambooom](https://github.com/bambooom/flask-bootstrap-table)